# How to change the color of stars when you hover over it in Woocommerce reviews?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to change the color of stars when you hover over it in Woocommerce reviews?
I am trying to change the blue color when hovering on some other, but so far without success.

```
p.stars.selected a.active:before {
    content: "\53";
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
p.stars.selected a:not(.active):before {
    content: "\53";
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
.star-2:hover:before,.star-3:hover:before,.star-4:hover:before,.star-5:hover:before,.star-1:hover:before{
    color: green;
}
```

[image: .]

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit difficult to solve, as the classes may be different for every theme. I'm guessing class names from the code you sent, CSS may look like this:

```
p.stars:hover a::before {
    color: green;
}
```

It changes the color of stars on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Try following CSS to change color of the review stars ;)

```
.product .star-rating span:before,
.product .star-rating:before {
    color: #ffff00;
}
```

or by inspect you can find the star class an change it in style file . 
but change all on child theme not main theme

Comment: @LevMyndra can i check page ? do you have any url ?